# Display last item from a for each loop

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-k2

I have a php document, and I would like to display a variable from the last item from an array.

This how I have it:

```
<?php if(count($items)): ?>
<?php foreach ($items as $key=>$item):?>

    <?php echo $lastone ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

use php end() method http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php to get last element.

Comment: Thanks swapnesh. Is it possible Upside down? I mean show the first?

Comment: @user2096761 please specify it a little bit more...not getting what exactly u want

Comment: To show the first element from the array, you mean? You can use `reset($array)` to get the first item, but you can also just use `$array[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

$items[0] may not work if your array is assoc array.

simply use array_pop($items) and array_shift($items) to get last and first item respectively.
As suggested by previous answer, use end() wherever possible.